# Download content from the internet with code

Tags: c#, automation, webserver, webclient

I have to download some content from a website every day so I figure it will be nice to have a program that will do it... The problem is that the website requires authentication.

My current solution is by using `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control. I currently do something like:

```
/* Create browser */
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

/* navigate to desired site */ 
browser.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/");

// wait for browser to download dom

/* Get all tags of type input */
var elements = browser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("input");

/* let's look for the one we are interested */
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement curInput in elements)
{
       if (curInput.GetAttribute("name") == "q") // 
       {
             curInput.SetAttribute("value", "I changed the value of this input");
             break;
       }
}

// etc
```

I think this approach works but is not the best solution. I have tried to use the webclient class and that seems to work but for some reason it does not work. I belive the reason why it does not work is because I have to save the cookies?

**So my question is** how will I be able to track all the bytes that get send to the server and all the bytes that get responded in order to download what I need. In other words I will like to have the webclient act as a webrowser and once I get to the part I need by just looking at the source I should be able to parser the data that I need.

I will appreciate if someone can show me an example of how to do so. Google chrome does a pretty good job displaying lots of information:
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Antonio

Comment: I hope that you are using the `DocumentCompleted` event to "// wait for browser to download dom"

Comment: "for some reason it does not work" - it would help if you'd show us what you've tried. If the authentication requires cookies then that might indeed be the issue.

Comment: If this task is an opportunity to practice some .NET development, then Good deal!!  Otherwise, maybe take a look at the curl utility.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the vague example. I am looking for an answer that will enable me to do what I need regardless of the website not just something specific to this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question:

1. The best utility i know to track traffic is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) (its free).
2. For sending advanced HTTP requests, you should use class `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, which also has property [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x86a1s60%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and `Headers`, allowing you to do what ever you want.

Hope it helps.